# CGAL: how to get all primitives within a given distance

Tags: c++, collision-detection, cgal, aabb

I need to implement a collision detection algorithm. I need to get all of the pairs of primitives (i.e. point-face pairs and edge-edge pairs), in which the two primitives are within a given distance.

With a large mesh, I chose CGAL::Surface_mesh as my basic mesh data structure, and I decided to use the AABB tree for efficiency. The [AABB Tree](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/) manual page provides several usages:

1. Intersections: about exact intersections

   - intersection tests: `do_intersect(), number_of_intersected_primitives(), all_intersected_primitives(), any_intersected_primitive()`, exact intersection checking
   - intersection constructions: `all_intersections(), any_intersection()`, both return intersection objects with given primitive
2. distance:

   - `closet_point(), closet_point_and_primitive()`. I may need something like this.

So I think I may custom this by myself. I noticed the [Square_distance()](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classAABBTraits.html#a4dfd5585e5b11a057f1223f024cf3e1c) and the [Compare_distance()](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classAABBTraits.html#aa600068262ed08a8e233ffc3e6ab3b0b) is used as a distance function, could I overload these functions like this

```
bool Compare_distance()
{
    float distance = /* ... */;
    float final_distance = distance - threshold;
    // ...
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: For collision detection it is much better to use OBB tree (oriented), because with AABB tree you will lose a lot of time on rebuilding of the tree after each rotation of primitives. But with OBB tree you will just apply the same transformation to the whole tree without rebuilding of it.

Comment: @llya I have considered OBB tree, while the positions of the points are changing over time (rather than a rigid body motion), does this make OBB tree more complicated? By the way, is there any OBB tree implementation that matches my requirement?

Comment: Ok, it was not clear, that your collided objects are not rigid. In this case (when your objects are flexible) AABB might be more effective. But if your flexible objects consists of few rigid parts, OBB is usually better (if you apply OBB to each of these rigid parts).